# Frequent BSOD on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

This just started this week, no new hardware, no major updates or software installs either before it started happening. The system will often start slowing down or hang completely before BSOD, and there doesn't seem to be any pattern of when it happens.

Either comes up as KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR, or simply says "A process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been terminated."

Searched around for issues, tried a lot of the common fixes - updated drivers, updated firmware on my harddrive since a lot of topics suggested that may be the problem, ran chkdsk didn't find any problems.

Here are pics of some of the many BSODs I've gotten: 
[image: bsod]

Is this a hardware or software issue? And how can I pinpoint which device or program is causing the problem?

Comment: Have you done [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) on your RAM to verify that it's okay and just eliminate that from the possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Given KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR, t  his is most likely a hard drive that's on its way [towards dying](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/blue-screen-with-this-error-code/03276fa2-6dcb-44d0-a778-499d5d00b65d). When it sputters, that will cause fluctuating responses until it completely stops, at which point you get an unresponsive system with the [error screen you posted above](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/270277-32-0x000000f4).

Strongly suggest getting a new drive and copying important files after you've installed the OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Bug Check 0xF4: CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION bug check has a value of 0x000000F4. This indicates that a process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been terminated.

In your case an important Windows Process died.

Check the dumps with WinDbg to see which process died:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks